# Nessus 5 installation not working

Tags: 12.04

I downloaded the Ubuntu 11.10 / Ubuntu 12.04 (64 bits):
Nessus-5.0.1-ubuntu1110_amd64.deb (25298 KB) from the following page:-

http://www.tenable.com/products/nessus/select-your-operating-system

opened up the file using Ubuntu Software Centre and clicked on the install button on it's right. It prompted for a password. I entered the password and the installation began. After the installation was completed, the install button appeared again. Tried to search the Nessus in Dashboard Home, but no success.
Help on this please !

Comment: Can you try installing it again, and post the output of `/var/log/apt/history.log` and `/var/log/apt/term.log`?

Comment: Download the debian installation (64 bits) Here is instruction [Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=tAMuZ5UZWWc)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

type 127.0.0.1 in your browser. it opens scanner page for `nessus`.

Comment: it displayed the following message:

Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to 127.0.0.1

Comment: They're having a problem installing Nessus, not accessing it.